# Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know that I should be using state for inputs, avoiding direct Dom access as much as possible in react, but this is a unique and necessary situation.

I found similar questions to this one, but I'm not able to replicate it in my specific case using 'reset()', can someone help me?

Code:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const infoInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

infoInputRef.current.reset();
```

Typescript error underlining **reset()**:

```
Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: What makes you think a `HTMLInputElement` should have a method named `reset()`?

Comment: Two things: 1) `but this is a unique and necessary situation.` - I strongly doubt it. 2) According to spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) there is no `reset` available on HTMLInputElement, so the error is correct.

Comment: Agree with both of you, but how should I reset my input?

Comment: `infoInputRef.current.value = ''` i guess.

Comment: Well, that depends what you understand by "reset" (probably setting its value to some default value) and where that default values comes from ... But generally this would be `infoInputRef.current.value = whateverDefaultValue`

Comment: @nbokmans about your "I strongly doubt it", I will use that as an advice and I will try to implement this using states. Now, since I`m new in stackoverflow, I need one more advice from you, should I remove this question? or leave it in case some else make the same mistake?